# Coefficients in the series expansion of a central manifold are all zero

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations, stability

I have a system of 4 ODEs, which linearized around the origin gives

$$
\begin{align}
&\dot{q_1}=a\, q_1\\
&\dot{q_2}=b\,q_2\\
&\dot{q_3}=0\\
&\dot{q_4}=c\,q_4
\end{align}
$$
with $a$, $b$ and $c$ three numbers with positive real part. To determine whether the origin be a source or a saddle I proceed to apply centre manifold theory. The system is already in coordinates in which the centre subspace coincides with one of the axes. Defining

$$
\begin{align}
&h_1(q_3)=a_2q_3^2+a_3q_3^3+a_4q_3^4\\
&h_2(q_3)=b_2q_3^2+b_3q_3^3+b_4q_3^4\\
&h_4(q_3)=c_2q_3^2+c_3q_3^3+c_4q_3^4
\end{align}
$$
and plugging these functions in the standard formula characterizing the centre manifold I obtain a system of equations which is satisfied only by

$$
a_2=a_3=a_4=b_2=b_3=b_4=c_2=c_3=c_4=0.
$$

How can I solve this problem?